# Highcharts multiple series in drill down

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following situation:

In my main series I would like to drill down on multiple sub series (same category). I have tried the id/name combination but this is limiting me to 1 serie only.

http://jsfiddle.net/B5XBm/2/

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
        {
            id: 'fruits',
            name: 'fruit 1',
            data: [2,3,6]

        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            name: 'fruit 2',
            data: [2,3,6]
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you really want? It looks like you started with the default, basic drilldown chart provided in the api.

Comment: I currently have a basic chart with the same categories (e.g.: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr) and multiple series (Serie 1/Serie 2/Serie 3) when clicking on Serie 1 I would like to see all sub series associated with Serie 1 based on the same categories (Jan/Feb/Mar), now this works for 1 series but when trying to add multiple series to the drilldown it always displays the last one added.

Comment: Not really, I would need multiple children series

Comment: @Steevo, Did you find the solution to multiple series. I am stuck in the same hell as you now.

Comment: @8.8.8.8 Not really... What I am doing now is filter my JSON based on drop downs at the top of my chart which is easier to do and gives more flexibility when adding new categories or data.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is taken from JSFiddle, and it remove the data from existing chart and add new series dynamically. Maybe this can satisfy you requirement.

```
function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
    chart_hook.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    while (chart_hook.series.length > 0) {
        chart_hook.series[0].remove(false);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        chart_hook.addSeries({
        name : name[i],
        data : data[i],
        color : color[i]
        });
    }
    chart_hook.redraw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by `drilldown.js` plugin. We have plans to add support for this, but nothing strict right now. Well, to be more specific, when you click on category label, then you will be able to drilldown to two series, but it's not possible to connect two drilldown-series to one point.

You can still use old solution with `setChart`, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7xEhW/131/).

Full explanation for `setChart` method can be found [here](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/drilldown-multi-series-datetime-t28687/#p100612).

Comment: Is there any plan to add this to drilldown.js plugin?